# Where to put static data in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. I'm trying to write a program that makes use of the MVVM design pattern.

My program has a list of countries that are fetched from the database on startup, and are static after that. Where is the place to put these? At the moment, I have them sitting at the top level of my ViewModel class hierarchy:

```
abstract class AbstractViewModel
{
    static Jurisdiction[] jurisdictionOptions;
    public Jurisdiction[] JurisdictionOptions
    {
        get {
            if (jurisdictionOptions == null)
            {
                using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
                {
                    jurisdictionOptions = db.Jurisdictions.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return jurisdictionOptions;
        }
    }
}
```

I can then set the `ItemSource` of UIElements to `JurisdictionOptions`.

Is this the correct way of implenting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are implementing the MVVM pattern you should also have a model class.

In general you should put your database code inside the model.

Comment: `Jurisdiction` is a model class. I'm using the entity framework to provide datadase access, and I didn't want to load the model classes it uses with too many extra methods. Maybe I need to introduce a new layer of classes between the entity framework classes and my viewmodels.